# Not fully downloaded blob: videos

Tags: javascript, python, html, blob

Hi developers i have some problems with blob videos for long time.So I think i finally got hierarchy of blob video that something like reads part of video from server and sends to client.But today i encounter some other problem.Firstly I searched from where comes this blob data to player and some articles gave me useful information for to refer to the links for blob that in inspect section of web page Network section on Chrome.

In this way i saw that the blob video downloads every few seconds with different urls but with little modification.The site was : https://www2.1movies.is/movie/xxxxxxxxxxxxx.html
Blob request refers to urls in a short time with only change of number like that:
s7--p.ex/ample--{seq-1}-xxxx.xxxxxxx
in this exapmle only seq 1 changes frequently and number increasing.
So i used python to download this video by parts in normal mode (without asyncio , or with another sophisticated ways).I did't know how many parts consists video and i checked manually untill it will give 404 error.I did't saved code i used cmd ,therefore i will give code with example.

```
import urllib as ur

def downloader(x):
    "Imagine we will call downloader with given seed url 
    for example site.com/seq-{}-signature=xxxxxx
    in there program will change number with format like that
    site.com/seq-1-signature=xxxxxx
    site.com/seq-2-signature=xxxxxx and so on.."
    for i in range(1,2000):
        try:
            "video will created with given namber like -> : 1.ts , 2.ts"
            ff=open("{}.ts".format(i),'wb')
            "and part of video will be read with url and write to file"
            ff.write(x.urlopen(x.format(i)).read())
            ff.close()
        except Exception:
            continue

>>>downloader('examp.ple/seq-{}-ddadadaad')
```

so program worked , but when i attempt to combine all video in one then i saw  all parts did't loaded fully , fr example  in network section 215th part show 300kb but downloaded file is 298kb.Therefore video playing like interrupted..

So maybe there are have other ways to download this kind of videos but if site works with this way , why didn't I succeed?